# Show specific number of items from array in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I have following code: [my code](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-cherry-nx6h9)

I need to check if my elements `name.length` sum count is greater than 25 then only show items whose `name.length` sum is less than 25. And also print `count` of items which are not shown.

I am trying something like this, but I stuck, please help :)

```
    const skills = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Html"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "css"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "bootstrap 4"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "scss"
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: "JS"
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      name: "React"
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      name: "Jquery"
    },
    {
      id: 8,
      name: "Vue JS"
     }
     ];
      return (
        <div>
          {skills.map((skill) => (
        <li key={skill.id}>{skill.name}</li>
      ))}
      {/* with this line I am wanting to show each elemet char count  */}
      {skills.map((skill) => (
        <div>{skill.name.length}</div>
      ))}
      {/* need to show hide elements count  */}
      <div>+{count}</div>
    </div>
  );
```

In the end I need to get view like this

- Html
- css
- bootstrap 4
- scss
- JS

+3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can approach this as:

```js
let lengthCount = 0;
let maxIndex = 0;

skills.map((item, index)=>{
 if(lengthCount <= 25 ){
   maxIndex = index;
   console.log("item: " , item.name)
 }
  lengthCount = lengthCount + item.name.length;
})

console.log("+",skills.length - maxIndex, " more");
```

Result:

[image]

Here is the link to codepen https://codepen.io/the_only_yasir/pen/dyOdZZR?editors=0010

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
 return (
    <div>
      {skills.map((skill) => {
        if (skill.name.length < 25) {
          return <li key={skill.id}>{skill.name}</li>;
        } else {
          countMoreThan25++;
        }
      })}
      +{countMoreThan25}
    </div>
  );
```

Here is the code for reference.
`https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-newton-qjxpw?file=/src/App.js:549-799`

Comment: Didn't he want to check total sum of names of items, and if that sum is less than 25?

Comment: Looking at the output I thought he wants to show the items if its char count is less than 25 else he want to show as "+{items} more" which have char count more than 25.